# SQL "to" key word -- specifically POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, keyword

What does the "to" keyword do in SQL, specifically POSTGRESQL.

I can verify that it is a keyword.

It is very hard to search on a simple word such as "to" however.

It doeesn't appear here for example:
https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_ref_keywords.asp

I don't know if this is specific to POSTGRESQL or more general ....

Comment: Tip: Whatever the problem is, w3schools is unlikely to help at all. It's the Wikihow of programming. Here is a *vastly* better [table of keywords from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words).

Comment: It appears to be a [SQL reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-keywords-appendix.html). It doesn't necessarily have to _do_ anything, i

Comment: The keyword has no special meaning in SQL. It occurs in certain contexts, such as RENAME TO. If you are looking for the meaning of a particular Postgres command, the most reliable source is the official documentation, e.g. [ALTER TABLE.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

Comment: If you don't want to go through [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) you can use [pg_get_keywords ()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.19.2.2.9.1.1.1) to query for specific words directly

Answer (score 3):

Searching the parser `src/backend/parser/gram.y` fot `TO`, you will find:

- `SET name TO 'var_value'`
- `INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE` (data type)
- `ALTER TABLE <name> OWNER TO RoleSpec`
- `FOR VALUES FROM '(' expr_list ')' TO '(' expr_list ')'` (partitioning)
- `COPY ( query ) TO file  [WITH] [(options)]`
- `ALTER EXTENSION name UPDATE [ TO version ]`
- `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA remote_schema [ { LIMIT TO | EXCEPT } ( table_list ) ]`
- `CREATE POLICY name ON table [AS { PERMISSIVE | RESTRICTIVE } ] [FOR { SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE } ] [TO role, ...] [USING (qual)] [WITH CHECK (with check qual)]`
- `ALTER TYPE_P any_name RENAME VALUE_P Sconst TO Sconst`
- `REASSIGN OWNED BY role_list TO RoleSpec`
- `GRANT privileges ON privilege_target TO grantee_list`
- `CREATE opt_or_replace TRANSFORM FOR Typename LANGUAGE name (TO SQL_P WITH FUNCTION function_with_argtypes)`
- `ALTER THING name RENAME TO newname`
- `CREATE opt_or_replace RULE name AS ON event TO qualified_name where_clause DO opt_instead RuleActionList`
- `ROLLBACK opt_transaction TO SAVEPOINT ColId`
- `CREATE [DEFAULT] CONVERSION <conversion_name> FOR <encoding_name> TO <encoding_name> FROM <func_name>`
- `a_expr SIMILAR TO a_expr`

Answer (score 2):

Keywords don't "do" anything, they're just reserved so that when implementing a SQL parser you can make assumptions about how to handle certain parts of the query.

In technical terms, any instance of `TO`, which is part of the [ISO 9075 SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2016) and used by all major SQL dialects, is treated as a *token* unless otherwise escaped.

What it "does" depends entirely on context. In some cases it's just decorative, while in others it's a required part of the syntax. It's simply used to express a particular statement.

Why? It's just how the syntax is defined.

Keep in mind SQL was designed to be a quasi English-like query language so the phrasing of certain statements reflects that. `INSERT INTO` could have been expressed as `INS` and it would operate just the same, but that's not how the designers wanted it to look.

Answer (score 1):

The `TO` keyword is used when setting run time parameters along with `SET`, for example `SET search_path TO my_schema, public;`

You can see it described in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-set.html

Since it's not part of the "normal" `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `CREATE` syntax you can see why it doesn't come up so often.

Edit: as a commenter very helpfully pointed out below, it's used in several places, including [grant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-grant.html) and [alter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-altertable.html) statements, etc. It sometimes fulfills the role of an equal sign (e.g. in setting parameters) and sometimes fulfills the role of identifying a person or thing affected (e.g. grant to), and sometimes expressing the end result of an action (rollback to, alter table to), depending on the particular statement. Just like "to" in English, it does a lot depending on context.

Comment: It's also part of `alter table ... rename TO ...` or `reassign ... TO ...` or `grant ... TO ...` or `rollback TO savepoint` and probably some more